# Launching Android app Icon Shows Misbehavior or delay?

Tags: android

i'm facing a delay of like 0.3 milli sec in showing the splash screen in my application.
When it launches black screen with a top header appears with app icon over the left for like 0.3 or 0.2 milli sec, then the splash screen displays[launcher activity]. I had this Splash activity set as launcher activity and it displays for 5 seconds, and there's no delay set manually in code. It can be happening if app is heavy or something i had missed in coding. pls help.

code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,        
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. 
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over

                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TabBar.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not use a splash screen in a android app. It's is not a design pattern and it is not necessary by the software architecture

Comment: I know but that's a requirement by client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't change theme because of API level constraints, I did find the answer :
in values/styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

It seems like it was the titlebar that was the issue actually.
Though there's another problem appears: a white splash appears and then my splash Image for 0.2 to 0.3 miliseconds what to do now??
Any suggestions??

Comment: Please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Splash Activity Theme in your Manifest

@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

or @android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar

depends on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to change or custom the app theme from manifest file: you will find it at :

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```